# iOS UIPickerView set icon on selection bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I would like to have a custom icon on my UIPickerView selection row as in the image below.. [image: custom UIPickerView selection icons]

I would like to add the icons in the red x on the image and I don't know exactly how can I do this or if I can do that. I could set my custom row view but this custom view will be placed on all rows and not on the selection only..

Any ideea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create three `UIImageView` objects with your X icon. Add them to your view overtop of the `UIPickerView`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea.. I don't know why I didn't thought at this as it is not a complex thing to do ;)